# Spring Boot OAuth2 Single Sign On Concept not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am trying to develop `OAuth2 Client` Application with Single Sign On. I have already developed Authorization Server and tested with Client Credentials flow and its working fine. But when I try to use Authorization Code Grant with Single Sign On I could not get it right.  Client application takes me to Login Screen when I access authenticated URL,  but once authenticated I am redirected to call back url that's fine. But afterwards I could not access any URL as it all authenticated URL are automatically redirected to CALL BACK url. I have permitted call back url in my Security class

My requirement is once authenticated it will allow other urls normally before authentication it should not allow any url.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/","/index.html", "/home.html", "/login**","/webjars/**", "/error**","/favicon.ico**","/oauth/token","/oauth/authorize**","/demo/1")
              .permitAll()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
              .formLogin().permitAll()
              .and()
              .httpBasic();
```

Here the call back url is `demo/1` and Spring Security is not permitting any other url here.

My requirement is once authenticated it should allow other urls normally before authentication it should not allow any url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/resources/**", "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/").permitAll().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").failureUrl("/")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .  I think I need to develop my own Success Handler and set flag as logged in the keep the flag in the session. so that further requests will be tracked and asserted whether the user is authenticated.